# Rvest - Can't read content of website - Don't know which nodes to select

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

**Description**

I am scraping a web-page to retrieve relevant data. As an example I'll use this URL:

**Example**

https://isbnsearch.org/search?s=THE+GODFATHER+%2C+Mario+Puzo

My first iteration is basically searching "The Godfather, Mario Puzo", and the results are shown in the URL posted.

**Problem**

I am trying to use `read_html()` but I don't know what to include in the `html_nodes()` function to retrieve any meaningful data. I tried using 'table' or things like that but didn't work: returns an empty list.

The ultimate goal is to obtain either ISBN-13 or ISBN-10 of the first result of the search.  I can take care of this,I just need to access the data.

I assume* the solution will look something like:

```
url <- 'https://isbnsearch.org/search?s=THE+GODFATHER+%2C+Mario+Puzo'

data<-read_html(url) %>% html_nodes("something") %>% #maybe another function
```

But I don't know, hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right-click on an ISBN in Chrome and choose "Inspect", you'll see that each search result is a list item with the following structure (omitting some of the elements for clarity):

```
<ul id="searchresults">
  <li>
    <div class="bookinfo">
      <h2><a href="/isbn/9780451205766">The Godfather: 50th Anniversary Edition</a></h2>    
        <p>Author: Mario Puzo</p>
        <p>ISBN-13: 9780451205766</p>
        <p>ISBN-10: 0451205766</p>
        <p class="clear"></p>
    </div>
  </li>
```

So the CSS selector for the elements that you want is `div.bookinfo p`.

You could retrieve the text of those paragraphs using:

```
p <- read_html("https://isbnsearch.org/search?s=THE+GODFATHER+%2C+Mario+Puzo")
p %>% 
  html_nodes("div.bookinfo p") %>% 
  html_text()
```

and then write some logic to access only the ISBN(s) of interest. For example, to return all ISBN using `grep`:

```
p %>% 
  html_nodes("div.bookinfo p") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  grep("ISBN*", ., value = TRUE)

 [1] "ISBN-13: 9780451205766" "ISBN-10: 0451205766"    "ISBN-13: 9780345441706" 
     "ISBN-10: 0345441702"    "ISBN-13: 9780345432407"
 [6] "ISBN-10: 0345432401"    "ISBN-13: 9780345412218" "ISBN-10: 0345412214"    
     "ISBN-13: 9780345476722" "ISBN-10: 0345476727"   
[11] "ISBN-13: 9781936530335" "ISBN-10: 1936530333"
```